# get text of a list on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I am trying to get value from an HTML list

```
<div id="test">
    <ul>     
       <li>C:\        
         <ul class="leftbutton" >                 
            <li value="List1">Folder 1</li>                 
            <li value="List2">Folder 2</li>                 
            <li value="List3">Folder 3</li>                 
            <li value="List4">Folder 4</li>                 
            <li value="List5">Folder 5</li>         
         </ul>     
      </li> 
    </ul>  
</div>
```

i used the following code

```
    $("#test li").live('click', function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

i get the alert as Folder 1 if i clicked the list1
Now my problem is that i need to get the alert as 
C:\Folder 1 if i click the List1 and C:\Folder 3 if i click list3

**EDIT:**
I am showing here is a directory structure treeview.
there will be more levels as there can be more sub folders
updated html code shown below

```
<div id="test">
        <ul>     
           <li>
             <span>C:\</span>       
             <ul class="leftbutton" >                 
                <li value="List1"><span>Folder1</span></li>                 
                <li value="List2"><span>Folder2</span></li>
                   <ul>
                      <li value="SubList1"><span>SubFolder1</span></li>                 
                      <li value="SubList2"><span>SubFolder2</span></li>
                   </ul>
                <li value="List3">Folder 3</li>                 
                <li value="List4">Folder 4</li>                 
                <li value="List5">Folder 5</li>         
             </ul>     
          </li> 
        </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to go up the tree more than once? For example `C:\ ` + `Folder 1` + `Subfolder 1` ..?

Comment: Not an answer, but if the html you posted is in your control, meaning if you can modify it, I'd strongly suggest you wrap the `C:\\` part in a `span` element or something similar. Your problem will be come more easier IMO.

Comment: @Shrikant: That’s also what I suggested in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458208/get-text-of-a-list-on-click-using-jquery/5458268#5458268

Comment: @Mathias, yeah, by the time I typed my comment, there were 6 answers. I suck at typing fast :)

Comment: @thirtydot my scenario is to show the directory structure it will be changing from time to time.as u said there will be more levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:
when i create the list i provided each list with an id
that defines the fullpath. some of the code i have used from the above answers.

```
$("#test li").live('click', function (event) {
    alert(this.id);
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @thirtydot in my scenario there is some problem with that code.thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to wrap the “C:\” text in a `<span>`, like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <ul>     
        <li><span>C:\</span>
            <ul class="leftbutton">                 
                <li value="List1">Folder 1</li>                 
                <li value="List2">Folder 2</li>                 
                <li value="List3">Folder 3</li>                 
                <li value="List4">Folder 4</li>                 
                <li value="List5">Folder 5</li>         
            </ul>     
        </li> 
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Then, in jQuery:

```
$('#test li li').live('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.parents('li').find('span').text() + $this.text());
});
```

This will also work if you add more list items, like `D:\` or `E:\`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/C6hdT/

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$("#test li").live('click', function (event) {
    alert('C:\' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: what if there were different drives?

Comment: mark your text 'C:\' as <span id="myId">C:\</span> and user $("myId").text();

Comment: @galimy I imagine @Suraj wants the "C:\" value (or whatever it might be) from the parent list-item, as opposed to being hard coded (although that is not entirely clear from the question).

Comment: @ZeSimon exactly there will be more drives and it is dynamic cannot be predicted how much subfolders are there.I cannot hard code the drive.

Comment: @w3d sorry for my incomplete question but what you told is my requirement.thanks for pointing me that.

Comment: in case with dynamic use $(this).parent().parent().find('span').text()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#test li").live('click', function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: why would that make any difference?

Comment: which is not the solution to his problem, but very nice indeed

Answer (score 0):

You have to work your way up the li tree once an li is clicked. In other words check if a parent li exists and prepend its value to the return string of the location.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to add only c:\ in your alert than simply try this

```
 $("#test>li").live('click', function (event) {
       $text=$(this).text());
       alert('C:\\'+$text)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#test li").click(function (event) {
      alert("C:\\"+ $(this).text());
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

you dont have to use `live` in this scenario as it is for binding events to the dynamically added elements in the DOM

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MD2K2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#test li").live('click', function (event) {         alert($(this+':child').text().substr(0,3)+$(this).text());     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require the extraneous `<span>` tags, and it will freely move up the tree.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/U8YXf/

```
$("#test li").live('click', function(event) {
    var path = '';
    $(this).parents('li').add(this).each(function() {
        path += $.trim($(this)[0].firstChild.nodeValue).replace(/\\$/, '') + '\\';
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(path);
});
```